# How can I justify the better performance of my optimization model than another model for the same problem?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization

There is a problem and, I have suggested two different models to solve it.

The first one is a model on a graph that it's corresponded optimization is like the blow where variable "x" is associated with edges:

$min \sum_{i \in [1,...,N]} \sum_{j \in [1,...,N]} x_{ij}$

$s.t.$

$x_{ij} \in [0,1]$

$constraint1.1$

$constraint1.2$

and the second one which has the better performance is based on an augmented graph with a different optimization programming that is:

$min \sum_{j \in [1,...,N]} x_{aj}$

$s.t.$

$x_{ij} \in [0,1]$

$constraint2.1$

$constraint2.2$

Where "a" is a determined node in the graph. Note that there is no huge difference between constraints in the two models so I ignore to define them precisely.

I want to know how I can justify the difference in performance between these two models based on their objectives.

Comment: Typical LPs use interior point methods. Say you start at the same initialization, and want to reach the same output, and further the feasible region under the constraint set is the same, then the only explanation is that it is taking longer to compute each update step of (1) than (2). This looks to be likely given the first has 2 summations in the optimization function vs the second LP.

Comment: @RahulMadhavan, how can I analyze the feasible region under the constraints of methods? Is there any way to compare them for the same initialization and the same output?

Comment: The feasible region means all points are valid as per the constraints. Therefore if you have similar constraints as you mention in the question  "Note that there is no huge difference between constraints", you should have the same feasible set.